# Page not found (404) in django project

Tags: python, django

The following is my code, when I tried it I get an error:

```
'accounts/register' could not be found
```

index.html:

```html
{% load static %}
{% static "images" as baseUrl %}
<!doctype html>
<!-- Website Template by freewebsitetemplates.com -->
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Mustache Enthusiast</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/mobile.css' %}" media="screen and (max-width : 568px)">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/mobile.js' %}"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <a href="{% static 'index.html' %}" class="logo">
            <img src="{% static 'images/logo.jpg' %}" alt="">
        </a>
        <ul id="navigation">
            <li class="selected">
                <a href="{% static 'index.html' %}">home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="{% static 'about.html' %}">about</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="{% static 'accounts/register' %}">register</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="{% static 'contact.html' %}">contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="body">
        <div id="featured">
            <img src="{% static 'images/the-beacon.jpg' %}" alt="">
            <div>
                <h2>the beacon to all mankind</h2>
                <span>Our website templates are created with</span>
                <span>inspiration, checked for quality and originality</span>
                <span>and meticulously sliced and coded.</span>
                <a href="{% static 'blog-single-post.html' %}" class="more">read more</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <ul>
            {% for cate in categos %}
            <li>
                <a href="{% static 'gallery.html' %}">
                    <img src="{{cate.img.url}}" alt="" style="width:240px;height:200px;">
                    <span>{{cate.name}}</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

register.html :

```html
{% load static%}
<!doctype html>
<!-- Website Template by freewebsitetemplates.com -->
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Mustache Enthusiast</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/mobile.css' %}" media="screen and (max-width : 568px)">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/mobile.js' %}"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <a href="{% static 'index.html' %}" class="logo">
            <img src="{% static 'images/logo.jpg' %}" alt="">
        </a>
        <ul id="navigation">
            <li class="selected">
                <a href="{% static 'index.html' %}">home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="{% static 'about.html' %}">about</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="{% static 'contact.html' %}">contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="body">
        <div id="featured">
            <img src="{% static 'images/the-beacon.jpg' %}" alt="">
            <div>
                <h2>Registration</h2>
                <form action="register" method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First name"><br>
                    <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last name"><br>
                    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"><br>
                    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email"><br>
                    <input type="password" name="password1" placeholder="Password"><br>
                    <input type="password" name="password2" placeholder="Confirm password"><br>
                    <input type="submit">
                </form>
                <a href="{% static 'blog-single-post.html' %}" class="more">read more</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

views.py in accounts app:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def register(request):
    return render(request,'register.html',)
```

urls.py in accounts app :

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('register', views.register, name='register')
    ]
```

models.py in propython :

```py
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class categories(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='pics')
```

views.py in propython

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import categories
# Create your views here.


def index(request):

    categos = categories.objects.all()

    return render(request,'index.html', {'categos': categos})
```

But I change chrome browser URL `http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/accounts/register` to
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/register` then my code run without any problem.

Comment: @Ajay Please correct all problems that you see in a post. You just corrected one word and added *Thanks in advanced*. **Don't** add salutations into a post. In-fact you should remove them.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the error is in your **register.html**, where you are initializing your form:

```
<form action="register" method="POST">
```

the `action` attribute accepts a **url** not a **string**, change it to this:

```
<form action="{% url 'register' %}" method="POST">
```

or add a slash before `register`:

```
<form action="/register" method="POST">
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is no path http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/accounts/register.
so when you change http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/accounts/register to http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/register, it should work properly. that's obvious. unless the path in your urls.py project be `static/accounts/`.

Comment: here is my urls.py what's the problem if you know let me know                                                                                                                                                                           from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('register', views.register, name='register')
    ]

Comment: I just read your comment. Did you solve it? If not then reply so that maybe ill can help

Answer (score 0):

The way you generate URLs in the template seems off.

The `static` tag is used to include static assets (images, CSS, JavaScript) in your code:

```
{% static "some_app/some_file.css" %}
```

The `url` tag is used to generate an URL, basing on your Django application URL configuration:

```
{% url "app_prefix:name" %}
```